# How to remove UIView from the superView with specific position programmatically

Tags: swift

I am new to swift, using swift 3, I built tableview that reads group of images and I want to have it as below:
when user select an image in the tableview I display it in an UIImageView and when Deselect an image he already selected in the tableview to be removed from the UIImageView ( Multiple Selection is enabled). My code below is working for one image selection only, however if multiple images are selected and then deselected the last selected one only removed from the UIImageview. So my question is how can I remove the UIImageview that belongs to the deselected record in the UItableview

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        image_view.image = UIImage(data: Saveddata[indexPath.row].photo as! Data)
             //create image view programmatically
            currentImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 130 + (i * 10), y: 50 + (i * 5), width: 50, height: 100))
             currentImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
             currentImageView.image = image_view.image
             view.addSubview(currentImageView as UIView)           
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       currentImageView.removeFromSuperview()


    }
```

Comment: You cannot simply remove view or UI component in `UITableViewCell`. it is reusable for other rows. What you can do is set a flag using Global array and keep `indexPath.row` as an index for those you have removed. Then in your `cellForRow`, check if that index occur, hide the image or change the `width` constraint to 0

Comment: avoid uisng `addSubview`, instead, use storyboard or xib with IBOutlet. This prevent creating duplicate view inside the cell

Comment: @h44f33z, thank you however I am not trying to remove it from the tableview I am trying to remove it from a UIview that I created and add the image to it when this image being selected in the tableview

Comment: try use `tag`. added my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tag` for each `UIImageView` based on the `indexPath.row` so you could refer by tag.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let image = UIImage(data: Saveddata[indexPath.row].photo as! Data)
    //create image view programmatically
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 130 + (i * 10), y: 50 + (i * 5), width: 50, height: 100))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.tag = 100 + indexPath.row
    imageView.image = image
    view.addSubview(imageView as UIView)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     // get imageView by its tag        
    let deselectedImageView = view.viewWithTag(100 + indexPath.row) as! UIImageView
    deselectedImageView.removeFromSuperview()


}
```

Comment: loved the idea however it returned an error: Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10ea19b40) to 'UIImageView' (0x10ea1b288).

Comment: @rania updated my answer by adding 100 to tag, so it would use tag 0

Comment: OMG thanks a million, it works now and I got it. appreciated your help really, have been looking for a way out for long time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your cell appearance when selected/deselected, you should override the method `setSelected(_:animated:)` inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass instead of trying to update it directly from your `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    // Do whatever you want depending on the selected value
}
```